# Why is there a different number of Stack Overflow Jobs postings on main page when accessing site from Germany and Slovakia?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I am developing simple tracking tool using Stack Overflow Jobs data (https://stackseeker.com/), but it looks like there is an issue.

Connecting from Slovakia I can see 2322 job postings on main page, but when trying to [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) the main page from the server in Germany I can see 15808 postings. Are job postings geographically filtered based on IP address? If so, is there possibility to disable this filter?

Comment: That spam add has been haywire forever - just ignore it. Right now among other things it says, in German, that I suggests I should move to Germany for a Python job... although I have never logged in on the site from Germany, don't want to move to Germany, don't know German, don't know Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SO Jobs are filtered by IP address. Clients have the option to hide their job listing from users outside a defined geographical area. We handle this by Geo IP matching.

You can work around this issue by using the RSS feed, http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed.